# For each employee how many work orders did they work on in 2018?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am still new to sql and I am trying to figure out for each employee how many work orders did they work on in the year 2018. I have two tables tblWorkOrder and tblTimeCharge they are both connected by the field IDEmployee.

tblWorkOrder has a column called DateCompleted which lets you know when the work order form was completed. However, Whenever I run my Code I get the error no such column.tblWorder.DateCompleted.

**Sample Code**

```
SELECT tblEmployee.IDEmployee, tblEmployee.FirstName, COUNT(tblTimeCharge.IDWorkOrder)
FROM tblEmployee LEFT JOIN tblTimeCharge ON tblTimeCharge.IDEmployee = tblEmployee.IDEmployee 
GROUP BY tblEmployee.IDEmployee, tblEmployee.FirstName
Having tblWorkOrder.DateCompleted between '01/01/2018' and '12/31/2018';
```

For my output I would like to have the employees first name as well as the count of how many workorders that were completed for that year.

```
CREATE TABLE tblEmployee(
  IDEmployee Integer NOT NULL Primary Key,
  LastName Text,
  FirstName Text,
  EmpNum Text,
  IDGender Integer,
  IDRace Integer,
  DOB Date,
  City Integer,
  State Text,
  TerminationDate Date,
  IDTerminationReason Date,
  Email Text,
  Phone Text,
  IDposition Integer,
  HireDate Date,
  Adjust Float,
  Foreign Key (IDGender) References tblGender(IDGender),
  Foreign Key (IDRace) References tblRace(IDRace),
  Foreign Key (IDTerminationReason) References tblTermination(IDTR),
  Foreign Key (IDPosition) References tblPosition(IDPosition)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE tblTimeCharge (
  IDTimeCharger Integer NOT NULL Primary Key,
  IDWorkOrder Integer,
  IDEmployee Integer,
  TimeChargeHours Integer,
  TimeChargeDate Date,
  Foreign Key (IDWorkOrder) References tblWorkOrder(IDWorkOrder),
  Foreign Key (IDEmployee) References tblEmployee(IDEmployee)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE tblWorkOrder (
  IDWorkOrder Integer NOT NULL Primary Key,
  WONNumber Integer,
  IDPriority Integer,
  IDCategory Integer,
  IDBldg Integer,
  Assigned Integer,
  DateAvailable Date,
  DateNeeded Date,
  DateCompleted Date,
  DateCreated Date,
  Foreign Key (IDPriority) References tblPriority(IDPriority),
  Foreign Key (IDCategory) References tblCategory(IDCategory),
  Foreign Key (IDBldg) References tblBuilding(IDBldg)
);
```

Comment: you actually have 3 tables: tblWorkOrder, tblTimeCharge and tblEmployee. Seeing their schemas would help

Comment: I added the schemas for the tables.

Answer (score 2):

Learn to use table aliases!  They make the query easier to write and to read!

```
SELECT e.IDEmployee, e.FirstName, COUNT(wc.IDWorkOrder)
FROM tblEmployee e LEFT JOIN 
     tblTimeCharge tc
     ON tc.IDEmployee = e.IDEmployee LEFT JOIN
     tblWorkCharge wc
     ON wc.IdWorkCharge= tc.WorkCharge AND
        wc.DateCompleted >= '2018-01-01' AND
        wc.DateCompleted < '2019-01-01' 
GROUP BY e.IDEmployee, e.FirstName;
```

The key here is putting the date comparisons in the `ON` clause, so the `LEFT JOIN` is not turned into an inner join.  Also note the use of standard date formats.

Comment: When I run this code I get the error saying no such column: tc.DateCompleted. I added the schema's for the tables if that might help.

Comment: @TrueNaijaKing . . . Your original question did not fully explain that there are three tables.  I modified the answer based on your revised question.

Answer (score 0):

This is wnat you want i beleive:

You were missing the table tblWorkOrder in your query

```
    SELECT tblEmployee.IDEmployee, tblEmployee.FirstName, 
    COUNT(tblTimeCharge.IDWorkOrder)
    FROM tblEmployee LEFT JOIN 
    tblTimeCharge ON tblTimeCharge.IDEmployee = tblEmployee.IDEmployee 
    inner join 
    tblWorkOrder  on tblTimeCharge.IDWorkOrder = tblWorkOrder.IDWorkOrder 
    GROUP BY tblEmployee.IDEmployee, tblEmployee.FirstName
    Having tblWorkOrder.DateCompleted between '01/01/2018' and '12/31/2018';
```

Comment: When I run this code I get the error saying no such column: tblWorkOrder.IDEmployee. I added the schema's for the tables if that might help.

Comment: You said:"I have two tables tblWorkOrder and tblTimeCharge they are both connected by the field IDEmployee." but they are connect by IDWorkOrder. I corrected the query, run it again

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT` join like this:

```
SELECT e.IDEmployee, e.FirstName, e.LastName,
  COUNT(t.IDWorkOrder)
FROM tblEmployee e 
LEFT JOIN tblTimeCharge t ON t.IDEmployee = e.IDEmployee 
LEFT JOIN tblWorkOrder w on w.IDWorkOrder = t.IDWorkOrder AND w.DateCompleted BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
GROUP BY e.IDEmployee, e.FirstName, e.LastName
```

I assume the dates in your table have the format `'YYYY-MM-DD'` which is comparable, if not then you should change it.